# Mongoose hooks via regEx not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to call certain hooks for my mongo collections when queries are performed on it.

```
DispatchRequest.findOneAndUpdate({user_name:"umesh"},{email:"a@gmail.com"},function(err,doc){
  if(err||!doc){
    return console.log("no such document found!!!!!!!",err,doc)
  }
})
```

On executing the above query, regEx based hooks are never triggered while those who take a string as input parameter are working fine.
ref: [mongoose docs for hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-post)

```
//never triggered
DispatchRequest.post(/^find/, async function () {
  console.log("FIND HOOK POST  IS CALLED") 
});

//never triggered
DispatchRequest.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  console.log("FIND HOOK PRE  IS CALLED")
});

//works fine
DispatchRequest.post("findOneAndUpdate", async function () {
  console.log("findOneAndUpdate  IS CALLED post", docToUpdate?.email)
});

//works fine
DispatchRequest.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function () {
  console.log("findOneAndUpdate  IS CALLED pre", docToUpdate?.email)
});
});
```

Mongoose Version: 5.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're using a slightly outdated version of Mongoose. The regex support was added in version 5.3. Look at the changelog [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#530--2018-09-28).

> feat(schema): support schema.pre(RegExp, fn) and schema.post(RegExp, fn) #6680

You'd need to update your Mongoose to a newer version (5.3+) or keep the old version but list all of the `find` methods that you want to hook into.

Comment: I have mongoose version 6.1.4 and it is still not working